# Simple C++ Array Logic Issue

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, isbn

I'm attempting to write a program in which the user enters an ISBN then checks the entry for accuracy. The ISBN is `0201702894`. The check digit (the 4) is calculated from the other 9 digits as follows – the (sum of each (digit times its position)) mod 11. `Ex: (0*1 + 2*2 + 0*3 + 1*4 + 7*5 + 0*6 + 2*7 + 8*8 + 9*9)%11 = (0+4+0+4+35+0+14+64+81)%11 = 4 (202/11 = 18 remainder 4)` The check digit can detect when an ISBN is entered or copied incorrectly.

Each time I enter values, I always have the "ISBN is not correct" output.  Something is wrong with my logic.

```
1.  Correct Value: 0201702894

2.  Incorrect value: 0201702984
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int totalNumbersCheck=0;

int main()
{
int isbnArray[10];      //array to store the ISBN numbers
int ISBN=0;             //inputted ISBN number

//user input

cout<<"Please enter the ISBN number: ";
cin>>ISBN;

//ISBN storage

isbnArray[ISBN];

//ISBN calculation

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    totalNumbersCheck=isbnArray[i]*(i+1);
}

//remove last element from array

    totalNumbersCheck-=isbnArray[10];

//check if remainder equals last element and output correct response

    if(totalNumbersCheck%11==isbnArray[10])
    {
        cout<<"\nThe ISBN is correct.";
    }
    else
        cout<<"\nThe ISBN is not correct.";

    cin.get();
    cin.get();

return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the isbn into a `std::string` variable, then loop through the characters in the string, convert each to a digit, and apply your algorithm.

```
const isbn_digits = 10;
std::string isbn;
std::cin >> isbn;
assert(isbn.size() == isbn_digits);
int sum = 0;
for (int pos = 0; pos < isbn_digits - 1; ++pos)
    sum += (pos + 1) * (isbn[pos] - '0');
if (sum % 11 != isbn[isbn_digits - 1] - '0')
    // error
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  isbnArray[ISBN];
```

is wrong, since ISBN is a 11 digit number which may start from 0. You would like to instead store each digit of the ISBN into the array `isbnArray`. Assume the input number is 1233445, this index is certainly out of your range of `isbnArray[9]`.

Meanwhile, the loop for computing the result may should look like this:

```
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
    totalNumbersCheck +=isbnArray[i]*(i+1);
 }

 if(totalNumbersCheck%11==isbnArray[9])
                   ///^^index out of bound again if you access isbnArray[9]
```

You know that ISBN is 11 digits, so you should at least use an array of length 11 not 9.

Comment: I now edited the array to utilize 10 elements because I start at 0 and I fixed the for loop.  Check again please.

Comment: @KlineTel you need an array of 11 in length so you can store 11 digits of the ISBN number. 10 is not enough

Comment: did you mean totalNumbersCheck+=isbnArray[i]*(i+1); instead of totalNumbersCheck=isbnArray[i]*(i+1); ?

Comment: @JulienGreard yeah. I updated it, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @KlineTel think about how to store the input ISBN number into your array isbnArray, simply doing isbnArray[ISBN] is wrong and will no do that